# How to challenge validity of housing inspections in regards to eviction

Tags: contract-law, landlord, australia, eviction

Jurisdiction is Western Australia.

If a landlord is experiencing financial troubles, and is attempting to evict their tenants on false grounds, in order to increase his sale price or make finding a buyer easier, how can those tenants challenge these false assertions and retain their tenancy?

The landlord is asserting lack of maintenance/cleaning of the property, including leaving tracks and windows dirty, whereas the tenant asserts that they are clean.

Is this behavior illegal? Can having a dirty rental be grounds for eviction, and if so, how can a tenant determine what maintenance is needed? Can the eviction be preemptively stopped or must it be challenged in court, and if so how?

Comment: Hi, welcome to law.SE! Your questions will probably be closed shortly, as it is asking for specific legal advice, which is [off-topic](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice). Please edit your question to ask about general legal information applicable to your situation. For example, you could ask "On what basis could my landlord evict me?" or "How does the upkeep of a house affect the eviction process" or similar.

Comment: Hi, Rozalija. Welcome to the StackExchange Network. I encourage you to take the  [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour), as we are a little different from other sites. In an attempt to keep your question open, and garner the answers you seek, I have edited your question to make it more general. You can see the edits I have made by clicking the "edited" link, above my name. If you feel that the edits that I have made have removed some of your question, please do not hesitate to edit the question further or revert it.